# Função Pyscript no html

Tags: html, python

Como eu faço para chamar uma função pyscript dentro do html?
Exemplo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <title>Py Test</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
  <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <py-script>
    def test():
      for x in range(4):
        print(x)
  </py-script>

  <button onClick="test()"> Teste </button>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar o atributo `py-*=""`, trocando o asterisco pelo evento que deseja. Segue a lista de eventos que você poderá adaptar ao `py-*`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element#events

No seu caso será o `py-click=""` e para manipular um elemento na página você pode usar o `pyscript.Element`

Exemplo de py-click e py-change:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
<script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>

<div id="id-foo-bar"></div>

<button py-click="ola_mundo1()">Testar</button>

<select py-change="ola_mundo2()">
   <option>valor 1</option>
   <option>valor 2</option>
</select>

<py-script>
# obtêm o elemento do contexto da página
elemento = Element("id-foo-bar").element

def ola_mundo1():
    elemento.innerHTML = "Olá Mundo (botão)!"

def ola_mundo2():
    elemento.innerHTML = "Olá Mundo (alterou o select)!"
</py-script>
```

Você também pode aplicar ou remover um evento dinamicamente você pode usar o `pyscript.Element` para aplicar ou o `import js`, e com `js.document` você vai poder acessar o contexto da página, mas para criar uma função que comunique terá que adiciona-la usando o método `create_proxy` do módulo `pyodide.ffi`

Exemplo:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
<script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>

<button id="id-botao">id-botao</button><hr>
<button class="classe-botao">classe-botao 0</button><br>
<button class="classe-botao">classe-botao 1</button><br>
<button class="classe-botao">classe-botao 2</button>

<py-script>
import js
from pyodide.ffi import create_proxy

# Element obtêm um elemento por ID
botao_por_id = pyscript.Element("id-botao").element

# js.document obtêm o DOM do contexto da página
botoes_por_classe = js.document.querySelectorAll(".classe-botao")

# cria a função
def ola_mundo(event):
    botoa_atual = event.target
    print("Olá, você clicou no botão:", botoa_atual.textContent)

# cria o proxy pra usar a função no elemento
proxy = create_proxy(ola_mundo)

# adiciona dinamicamente a função
botao_por_id.addEventListener("click", proxy)

# Com for você itera os botões com atributo class="classe-botao"
for botao in botoes_por_classe:
    # adiciona dinamicamente a função
    botao.addEventListener("click", proxy)
</py-script>
```

E você também pode adicionar um evento sem usar o proxy, usando o método `add_event_listener` do `pyodide.ffi.wrappers`, tornando as vezes mais simples:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
<script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>

<button id="id-1">Botão id-1</button>
<button id="id-2">Botão id-2</button>

<py-script>
from js import document
from pyodide.ffi.wrappers import add_event_listener

def ola_mundo(event):
    botoa_atual = event.target
    print("Olá, você clicou no botão:", botoa_atual.textContent)

# Com Element
botao_1 = pyscript.Element("id-1").element

# Com js
botao_2 = document.getElementById("id-2")

add_event_listener(botao_1, "click", ola_mundo)
add_event_listener(botao_2, "click", ola_mundo)
</py-script>
```

---

## Referências:

- https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/guides/event-handlers.html
- https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/tutorials/py-click.html
- https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/tutorials/writing-to-page.html